# Spring boot application to read from a properties file of a jar added as a dependency while running test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application and it has another spring application included as a jar in maven dependency. In that jar, i have a properties file under

```
src/main/resources/data.properties
```

Another file is present for testing

```
src/test/resources/data.properties
```

Now when i am running my main application test, then i want it to use the file under src/test/resources of that jar.

I tried doing below in my Test config class. But it fails with a file not found exception.
Is there a way i can load the file in the test/resources

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.app" }, excludeFilters = {
@PropertySource(value = {"file:/myApp/src/test/resources/data.properties"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading the properties from a file you could load it from the classpath, which would also solve the issue that for the test, you want to get the one on your `test/resources`

```java
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:data.properties"})
```

Comment: its not working this way... it is not reading from the jar.. still gives file not found exception

Comment: what jar file? you just mentioned `src/main/resources/` and `src/test/resources` in your question.

Comment: i mentioned this: I have a spring boot application and it has another spring application included as a jar in maven dependency. In that jar, i have a properties file under

src/main/resources/data.properties
Another file is present for testing

src/test/resources/data.properties